# cannot draw on texture

Tags: texture-painting

Im new and I am currently making the donut. For some reasons I can't paint on it, does anyone know how I can solve this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, you need to add a texture paint slot, found under the tools tab at the very top. Just click the part that says "add texture paint slot" pick "base color" set the resolution and I ASSUME that will fix your problem.